# Go sync.Pool undefined

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I have the following error when running a local Go server:

> Failed to build Go application:
>   /Users/toast/Downloads/server/github.com/bradfitz/http2/hpack/huffman.go:14:
>   undefined: sync.Pool

The code successfully ran and was deployed 6 weeks ago and now throws this error. Below is the Go version:

> go version go1.5.3 darwin/amd64

Any ideas why?

Comment: You're building something with go1.2 or older to get the `undefined: sync.Pool` error. You tagged this with app engine so your go version probably isn't go1.5.3.

Comment: @JimB You're right, why does 'go version' differ from 'goapp version'?

Comment: Because they are 2 different tools, and the appengine sdk includes the supported version of go.